# Running git bash in background/as daemon

Tags: eclipse, bash, git

I'm running my git bash using Eclipse Builders, which will trigger `npm run` scripts when my javascript is updated. Whenever I save a javascript, the git bash terminal appears for a short while before it's dismissed. Is there any arguments that will make the bash not open at all?

[image: My Eclipse Builder]

Comment: Does directly `npm.exe` with the arguments `run transpile` work instead of via `git-bash.exe`?

Comment: it seems that I do not have an npm.exe present anywhere in my installation. I downloaded node for windows and it pulled in npm in node_modules but it's not in .exe format.

Comment: What did you get if you run `where npm` on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve running a command without the popup appearing (and vbscript doesn't work in Eclipse builder for some weird reason), I created a `.bat` file and a `task` folder in my project instead.

**Current setup**:

[image]

**`.bat` file content**

```
start /MIN cmd /c "npm run transpile"
exit
```

Comment: Does it also work without the batch file by using as _Location_ `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` and as _Arguments_ `/C npm run transpile`?

Comment: I will give that a try later but I will also need to provide extra commands so that it points to the projects' directory. Probably easier to do that in `bat` file rather than eclipse builder

Comment: If there are only a few commands you can use `/C <command1> && <command2> && <command3>`...